# How to count number of total items where a class references itself

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am new to scala. I need to count Number of categories in the List, and I am trying to build a tail recursive function, without any success.

```
case class Category(name:String, children: List[Category])

val lists = List(
  Category("1",
    List(Category("1.1",
      List(Category("1.2", Nil))
    ))
  )
  ,Category("2", Nil),
  Category("3",
    List(Category("3.1", Nil))
  )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem regarding the tail-recursive function?

Comment: Making it tail recursive could be difficult since you are traversing a tree like data structure. Basically the only way to do it is to keep a list of all the work still to do (could e.g. be of type List[category] which would then be used like a stack) and make that an argument to the function.

Comment: @SpiderPig You only need an accumulator that contains the current count.

Comment: so, where is the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nyavro's solution can be made much faster (by several orders of magnitude) if you use Lists instead of Streams and also append elements at the front.
That's because x.children is usually a lot shorter than xs and Scala's List is an immutable singly linked list making prepend operations a lot faster than append operations.
Here is an example

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

case class Category(name:String, children: List[Category])

@tailrec
def childCount(cats:Stream[Category], acc:Int):Int =
  cats match {
    case Stream.Empty => acc
    case x #:: xs => childCount(xs ++ x.children, acc+1)
  }

@tailrec
def childCount2(cats: List[Category], acc:Int): Int =
  cats match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs => childCount2(x.children ++ xs, acc + 1)
  }

def generate(depth: Int, children: Int): List[Category] = {
  if(depth == 0) Nil
  else (0 until children).map(i => Category("abc", generate(depth - 1, children))).toList
}

val list = generate(8, 3)

var start = System.nanoTime
var count = childCount(list.toStream, 0)
var end = System.nanoTime
println("count: " + count)
println("time: " + ((end - start)/1e6) + "ms")

start = System.nanoTime
count = childCount2(list, 0)
end = System.nanoTime
println("count: " + count)
println("time: " + ((end - start)/1e6) + "ms")
```

output:

```
count: 9840
time: 2226.761485ms
count: 9840
time: 3.90171ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I was stuck as I was trying to solve it with List's size function, thus trying to avoid iterating through each item of the list. But I believe this is better solution and will go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following idea.

Lets define function *childCount*, taking collection of categories (cats) and number of children count so far (acc). To organize tail-recursive processing we take first child from collection and incrementing the acc. So we have processed first item but got some more items to process - children of first element. The idea is to put these unprocessed children to the end of children collection and call *childCount* again.

You can implement it this way:

```
@tailrec
def childCount(cats:Stream[Category], acc:Int):Int = 
  cats match {
    case Stream.Empty => acc
    case x #:: xs => childCount(xs ++ x.children, acc+1)
  }
```

call it:

```
val count = childCount(lists.toStream, 0)
```

Comment: This will run extremely slow if you have a large number of categories to count. To make it fast replace `Stream[Category]` with `List[Category]`, `x #:: xs` with `x :: xs` and `xs ++ x.children` with `x.children ++ xs`.

Comment: Why do you think implementation based on List is going to run faster? Why do you think that insertion of x.children at the beginning is better than appending to the end? Anyway, concatenation of Lists 'unwinds' the first list and inserts elements to the beginning of the second. Isn't Streams concatination lazy?

Comment: Lazy doesn't always mean faster. Also if you concatenate a list to a stream you have all the elements in memory anyway despite the laziness.
I tested the speed and I posted an answer with my results.